# how to remove many last character in delphi, but still keep 2 characters in front?

Tags: delphi

I have many strings, they are like:

```
75@1Mbps
36@24Mbps
67@9Mbps
76@HT20-0 
77@HT20-1
```

I want keep 2 string in front and remove all others, so they become:

```
75
36
67
76 
77
78
```

I can remove last string by this:

`Edit1.Text := copy(Edit1.Text, 1, Length(Edit1.Text)-5);`

But in my data the last string was `5` or `6` string need to be removed.

Answer (score 6):

Since the strings you want to keep are all the same length, you can simply use this:

```pascal
Edit1.Text := Copy(Edit1.Text, 1, 2);
```

Or, you can use one of these:

```pascal
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := Edit1.Text;
  SetLength(s, 2);
  Edit1.Text := s;
end;
```

```pascal
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := Edit1.Text;
  Delete(s, 3, MaxInt);
  Edit1.Text := s;
end;
```

However, if the position of the `@` ever changes, it is better to search for it dynamically instead, eg:

```pascal
var
  s: string;
  p: Integer;
begin
  s := Edit1.Text;
  p := Pos('@', s);
  Edit1.Text := Copy(s, 1, p - 1);
end;
```

```pascal
var
  s: string;
  p: Integer;
begin
  s := Edit1.Text;
  p := Pos('@', s);
  SetLength(s, p - 1);
  Edit1.Text := s;
end;
```

```pascal
var
  s: string;
  p: Integer;
begin
  s := Edit1.Text;
  p := Pos('@', s);
  Delete(s, p, MaxInt);
  Edit1.Text := s;
end;
```

Comment: Why not make use of method [Delete](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Delete) that is made for such purpose.

Comment: @SilverWarior: The `Delete` procedure is needlessly inefficient in this case.

Comment: Edit1.Text := Copy(Edit1.Text, 1, 2); I use it, bro Remy.. thanks